# How do I include the Amazon EC2 library for Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to run a simple node.js script to describe an instance, but I get:

module.js: 340

Error: Cannot find module 'aws-lib'

I have all the EC2 node.js library files in the same directory as the script, but how do I include them?

`var aws = require("aws-lib");`

`ec2 = aws.createEC2Client(*redacted*, *redacted*);`

`ec2.call("DescribeInstances", {}, function(err, result) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
});`

Comment: did you install aws-lib ? npm install aws-lib

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't install the module actually. Go the folder where your node application exists, then install the module there, like:

```
cd /path/to/your/node/application/    // Since you should be in your app folder
sudo npm cache clear // Just in case
sudo npm install aws-lib  // Actual loading command
```

These commands will create a folder called `node_modules` in your application folder. Then you can use `aws-lib`.

Comment: When you say node application, do you mean my node.js install, or the script I'm working on?

Comment: Cool beans.  I shall give that a whirl.

Comment: Two issues:


1) npm command not found (I'm running CentOS 6.3)
*EDIT* Installing npm right now


2) how would I do this in a Windows environment?

Comment: nodejs installation brings with npm. In windows, just install node, cheers

Comment: Tolga, thanks!  Not getting any library errors anymore!  And my script is running!